# Wolbachia - cytoplasmic incompatibility

Tags: evolution, entomology, pathology, infection

I read that cytoplasmic incompatibility in Wolbachia occurs when wolbachia-infected male insects mate with wolbachia-free female insects and produce non-viable offspring. By contrast, wolbachia-infected female hosts produce successful offspring irrespective of the infection status of their mate.

I was wondering - what are the long-term effects of this on the size/structure of a insect population? How will this be different from a non-infected population?